# Will bark-beetles infest the Methow Valley?

Tags: ecology, landscape-ecology

What is the Methow Valley (esp. Winthrop, WA) area's susceptibility to bark beetles?  Did the 2014 Carlton Complex wildfires increase the vulnerability due to the large numbers of dead, dying, and stressed pine and fir species in the area.  Are there ways I can reduce the vulnerability of my property, which is already in open, park-like stands?

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble finding any academic or governmental references for rates of spread of Scolytids (bark beetles) in your region, but the answer to this would require speculation (i.e. prediction). Many factors, including [the 'health' of the trees](https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/5/3/805/htm) surrounding your home, and the connectivity of your trees to invaded areas, would aid in bark predicting whether these beetles will eventually make their way onto your property.

If your property is large, consider [cost-share programs for management/prevention](https://www.dnr.wa.gov/news/bark-beetles-attacking-drought-stressed-douglas-fir-trees-across-washington) in your area.

See the bottom of [this .gov webpage](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7421.html) for more references. Good luck.